# ERROR Input length = 1 using sbt 1.2.8 scala 2.12.10 play 2.8.1

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, scalac

I'm developing a Play! application using sbt 1.2.8 scala 2.12.10
I'm trying to upgrade Play from 2.7.4 to **2.8.1**, but during compilation I get **[error] Input length = 1**. No stack trace, nothing. It was compiling up until 2.7.4.

I've found `java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1` result with Google, but I can't imagine how that could be relevant to Play! version bump.

The scalac options:

```
    "-deprecation","-explaintypes", "-feature", "-unchecked", "-language:_", "-Xlint",
    "-Ywarn-dead-code",  "-Ywarn-extra-implicit", "-Ywarn-inaccessible",
    "-Ywarn-infer-any", "-Ywarn-nullary-override",  "-Ywarn-nullary-unit",  
    "-Ywarn-unused:implicits", "-Ywarn-unused:locals",   "-Ywarn-unused:patvars",          
    "-Ywarn-unused:privates"
```

Any clues would be appreciated

Comment: Does it work with `sbt.version=1.3.5`?